# C++ Inheritance. Object calls super-class method instead of its own method?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

So I have 2 classes,

```
class Animal{
public:
    Animal(int age, int hairCount) {
        howOld = age;
        numOfHairs = hairCount;
    }

    void print(){
        cout << "Age: " << howOld << "\tNumber of Hairs: " << numOfHairs << endl;
    }

protected:
    int howOld;
    int numOfHairs;
};



class Bird: public Animal{
public:
    Bird(int age, int hairCount, bool fly) : Animal(age, hairCount) {
        canItFly = fly;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "Age: " << howOld << "\tNumber of Hairs: " 
             << numOfHairs << "\tAbility to fly: " << canItFly << endl;
    }
protected:
    bool canItFly;
};
```

If in the main program, I have something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<Animal> list;
    list.pushBack(Bird(5,10000,true));
    list.pushBack(Animal(14,1234567));

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        list[i].print(); //Calls the super class for both outputs
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, my code (this isn't it) calls the super class' print method under both circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare a member function

```
void print()
```

to be virtual i.e.

```
virtual void print()
```

Additionaly to that you should create a vector of pointers to Animal

```
vector<Animal *>
```

In main create new objects using new. Then it will work as expected. That said your main should look like this

```
vector<Animal *> list;
Animal *bird = new Bird(5,10000,true);
Animal *animal = new Animal(14,1234567);
list.push_back(bird);
list.push_back(animal);
```

And do not forget to delete bird and animal if you do not need them anymore by

```
delete bird;
delete animal;
```

Optionally you can use one of smart pointer classes, as suggested by Benjamin Lindley.

Comment: EDIT: I left out that little detail. I do have virtual on the super class. Not sure why it's not printing.

Comment: I can't call the print method using list[i].print() after declaring the vector like that.

Comment: Overriding functions are automatically `virtual` if the base function is.

Comment: @chickeneaterguy: Then call it like this: `list[i]->print()`

Comment: You need to have the keyword "virtual" to *every* method of the superclass that you will ever want a subclass to override. That's true in [C++](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes#Dynamic_polymorphism_.28Overrides.29) as well as [C#](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Keywords/virtual).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the arrow operator...haha.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do polymorphism with statically typed objects.  You need to use pointers or references.  Try a `vector<unique_ptr<Animal>>` to avoid memory management headaches.

Answer (score 4):

you just ran into object slicing :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

as others said, you can't staticly declare an array of Animals, as it will only make enough space to store animal, and things like birds will get sliced.

Comment: +1. Yes. Instead, you must declare an array of references to Animals (or pointers to Animals).

Comment: YES, I forgot about this too!

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism only affects **references** and **pointers**:

```
Bird bibo;
Crocodile claus;

Animal & a1 = bibo, & a2 = claus;

a1.print();
a2.print();
```

Having just a generic `Animal a` doesn't give you access to any polymorphic behaviour, and in fact it probably doesn't even make sense: Since every animal is a concrete animal of some type, your base class should probably be abstract.

Now what about containers? Since the concrete classes that derive from the base class can have variable sizes, there's no way you can put them into a container directly. Instead, you should point a *pointer* to the base class into the container.

The pointer of choice is `std::unique_ptr<Animal>`, which is lightweight and the simplest form of lifetime management. It works like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

typedef unique_ptr<Animal> AnimalPtr;
typedef std::vector<AnimalPtr> Zoo;

Zoo z;

z.push_back(AnimalPtr(new Bird));   // old-style
z.emplace_back(new Crocodile);      // new-style, better
```

Finally, a little obscure detail on how to make `Animal` abstract. We could declare `print()` to be pure virtual. Yet we also want a base implementation. We can do both:

```
struct Animal
{
  virtual void print() const = 0;
  // ...
};
void Animal::print() const
{
  out << "Age: " << howOld << "\tNumber of Hairs: " << numOfHairs << endl;
}

struct Bird
{
  virtual void print() const
  {
    Animal::print();  //  call base function first
    cout << "Ability to fly: " << canItFly << endl;
  }
  // ...
};
```